# React-table does not show \ character in message

Tags: character, react-table, backslash, presentation

Results in my react table should be like this:

"/.\u0010\u0016u/LGIRLGAV0735017500099A925",

but the result looks like this:
"/.■■u/LGIRLGAV0735017500099A925".

Black squares are actualy empty (only borders).
How to avoid the backslash character being displayed as an empty square?
Also, everithing in between backslashes missing.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

\ character followed with some other characters represents JS escape character. In my case \ was followed with u0012 (ie. \u0012). That was presented as: .■.

I was solve the problem in columns.js (subcomponent of React-Table) with JSON.stringify() method. This is most important for this problem, other
is just formating of my print.
`// replace null result with '' function replacer(key, value) { // Filtering out properties if (value === null) { return ''; } return value; }  export const COLUMNS = [        { Header: "Text", accessor: "text", Cell: ({ value }) => { return JSON.stringify(value, replacer,  '').replace(/"/g, '').split("").join(" ")}, },`